# i am using anjlab library for in app billing but " bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle() " always returning false

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Here bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle() is always returning false so the code is not getting executed and ads are showing even if the purchase is madde

Here is the link to anjlab billing library documentation:
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

I have tried the following code .The method restore() is being called inside the onCreate().

```java
public void restore(){
        if (bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()){
            if (bp.isPurchased("remove_ads")){
                FancyToast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pro Version Restored",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.INFO,true).show();
                CoordinatorLayout adscontainer = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
                View admobAds = (View) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                adscontainer.removeView(admobAds);
            }
            else
                {
                MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-8443413787087664~2607463808");
                mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

                loadInterstitialAd();
                ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("hello","world");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    Log.d("TAG","Interstitial Ad not loaded");
                                }
                                loadInterstitialAd();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                },30,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    }
```

The ads shouldnt get loaded if the user has purchased pro product.